# Java, MalformedURLException

Tags: java, java-8

I'm using `java.net.URL`, but I'm receiving a `MalformedURLException`. I've tried looking through the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Below is a sample of my code that is fired when a button is pressed.

```
public class DownloadController {
    public void downloadResource() {
        URL obj = new URL("http://www.example.com/docs/resource1.html");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using IntelliJ. There is no more code to show, the above code is literally the controller. I've only just started working on it.

Comment: Maybe an hidden extra character?

Comment: Do you use an IDE? It seems you do coding with a normal text editor!

Comment: @JeanValjean I use IntelliJ

Comment: @BugHunterUK IntelliJ makes the new URL stuff underlined with a red color! Strange that you did not see it!

Comment: @JeanValjean I did. And when I hovered over it, it was showing the error. Heres an image: http://i.imgur.com/ysyWI5y.png ... thats the error I was referring to. I now see it says "Unhandled Exception". I see what you mean. Could have solved it without the question. My bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The URL is fine. You're not *receiving* a `MalformedURLException`; you're getting a compile-time error about not *handling* one *if* one were thrown.             It won't happen with the given URL, but the compiler doesn't know that.

You need to either add a `try`/`catch` clause:

```
public void downloadResource() {
    try {
        URL obj = new URL("http://www.example.com/docs/resource1.html");
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
        // You could re-throw the exception as a runtime exception which doesn't
        // need to be caught.
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    } 
}
```

or add a `throws` clause:

```
public void downloadResource() throws MalformedURLException {
    URL obj = new URL("http://www.example.com/docs/resource1.html");
}
```